# Meta data in python classes

Tags: python, metadata

I have seen in some python libraries a common pattern to use a class definition named Meta inside the object, like django Models or tastypie Resources. Also some others doesn't use this like Celery Tasks.

*Is there any obvious reason for this?* from the tastypie code I can see that some metaclass is playing with the inner Meta class definition. *Is there any difference in meta-data and just plain attributes of the model?* in django models is kind of easy to say: attributes are just the fields like age = IntegerField, but I can think in attribute called fields, or just use _attrs or __attrs for the metadata.

*Is this consider a good practice?*

Bye.

Edited:

I would like to add something to this:

Are there any more libraries approaching this in a similar way? or there are different ways to do the same? is there any common pattern in here that I could check? Thanks.

I want to start a library and I like both ways, and is not related too much with this two libraries, so there's not consistency issues with selecting one or the other

Bye.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is no other difference than just convention: TastyPie just uses the same convention Django models use to separate "data" from "metadata" (data about the data).

### Metaclass and `Meta` class

Also, metaclass has access to both class attributes and inner classes, so this does not play any significant role.

### Why not `_attrs` or `__attrs`?

You could name it `_attrs` (maybe not `__attrs` due to name-mangling mechanism), but the convention is different (and the leading underscore means the API is not public).

### Why `Meta` in TastyPie?

As for the reason in case of TastyPie and `Meta` inner class for storing options, I suggest to watch the presentation of Daniel Lindsley (the creator of TastyPie) named "*API Design Tips*", that took place during latest DjangoCon US 2012: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKQzXu43hzY - it clearly shows the reasons for using this specific approach to building TastyPie's API.

### A little bit about consistency

When it comes to "*Is this considered a good practice?*" part, I would quote part of PEP8 ("the style guide", especially [part about consistency](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)):

> A style guide is about consistency. Consistency with this style guide is important. Consistency within a project is more important. Consistency within one module or function is most important.

So I would treat this approach (the approach in TastyPie) as a sign of consistency with the framework for which it was developed (namely: Django).

### A word about good practice

And yes, it **is a good practice** (to be consistent). It is also a good practice to use naming convention from Python Style Guide (PEP8), because it is widely adopted. However, using `Meta` inner class is just a convention - if you are writing some extension for Celery Tasks, better stick to their naming convention to not confuse users.

Comment: Thanks, I get the point with the consistency, it makes a lot of sense. I would like to change then a little bit my question, is there any more libraries approaching this in a similar way? or there are different ways to do the same? is there any common pattern in here that I could check? Thanks. I want to start a library and I like both ways, and is not related too much with this two libraries, so there's not consistency issues with selecting one or the other.